# java.lang.NullPointerException when accessing a vector2 array

Tags: java

i have 2 classes, AI.java and TestColl.java.

TestColl.java has the same problem as AI.java

the following block of codes are from AI.java.

```
public Vector2[] spawn = new Vector2[2];
public Vector2[] EnemPos = new Vector2[spawn.length];
public Vector2[] EnemVel = new Vector2[spawn.length];

 public void PlaceEnemy(){
    for(int i = 0; i < spawn.length;i++)//places enemies for the first time.
    {
        EnemPos[i] = new Vector2(0, 0);
        EnemVel[i] = new Vector2(0, 0);
        Gdx.app.log(log, "Creating EnemPos[" + Integer.toString(i) +"].x = " + Float.toString(EnemPos[i].x));
        Gdx.app.log(log, "Creating EnemPos[" + Integer.toString(i) +"].y = " + Float.toString(EnemPos[i].y));
        Gdx.app.log(log, "Creating EnemVel[" + Integer.toString(i) +"].x = " + Float.toString(EnemVel[i].x));
        Gdx.app.log(log, "Creating EnemVel[" + Integer.toString(i) +"].y = " + Float.toString(EnemVel[i].y));
        x = MathUtils.random(10,50);
        y = MathUtils.random(10,50);
        spawn[i] = new Vector2(x, y);
        Gdx.app.log(log, "spawn["+ i + "], " + Float.toString(spawn[i].x) + ", " + Float.toString(spawn[i].y));
    }
}
```

in PlaceEnemy method most of my vector variables have been given values. BUT! when i access them, the vector2 variables, from another method they return null.

for example. i'll call LogicChase() method to apply the AI for my Enemies.

the following block of codes are still inside AI.java class.

```
public void Decider(){
    if(!decision){
        // reason why it's 50/50 is that 
        // we will lower or raise the chance of having chasing = true
        // when the time comes but for now it's only at 50/50
        Random rand = new Random();
        int Choose = rand.nextInt(100);

        if(Choose <= 50){
            chasing = true;
        }

        else if(Choose > 50){
            chasing = false;
        }
        decision = true;
    }
}

public float chooseRandomDirection(){
    Random r = new Random();
    float[] randDirection = new float[3];
    randDirection[0] = 0;
    randDirection[1] = 1;
    randDirection[2] = -1;
    int randChoice = r.nextInt(3);
    return randDirection[randChoice];
}

public void setXDirection(float dir, int i){
    EnemVel[i].x = 0;
    Gdx.app.log(log, "Old EnemVel[" + Integer.toString(i) +"].x = " + Float.toString(EnemVel[i].x));
    EnemVel[i].x = dir;
    Gdx.app.log(log, "New EnemVel[" + Integer.toString(i) +"].x = " + Float.toString(EnemVel[i].x));
}

public void setYDirection(float dir, int i){
    EnemVel[i].y = 0;
    Gdx.app.log(log, "Old EnemVel[" + Integer.toString(i) +"].y = " + Float.toString(EnemVel[i].y));
    EnemVel[i].y = dir;
    Gdx.app.log(log, "New EnemVel[" + Integer.toString(i) +"].y = " + Float.toString(EnemVel[i].y));
}

public void move(int i){
    spawn[i].x += (Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()* (velocity/2)) * EnemVel[i].x;
    spawn[i].y += (Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()* (velocity/2)) * EnemVel[i].y;
}

public void logicChase() 
{
    for(int i=0; i<spawn.length; i++){
        Gdx.app.log(log, "Old EnemVel[" + Integer.toString(i) +"].x = " + Float.toString(EnemVel[i].x));
        Gdx.app.log(log, "Old EnemVel[" + Integer.toString(i) +"].y = " + Float.toString(EnemVel[i].y));
        Gdx.app.log(log, "Old EnemPos[" + Integer.toString(i) +"].x = " + Float.toString(EnemPos[i].x));
        Gdx.app.log(log, "Old EnemPos[" + Integer.toString(i) +"].y = " + Float.toString(EnemPos[i].y));
    }
    Decider();
    if(!chasing){// if not in chase mode.
        if(!moving){// if stationary.
            if(!lock){// if directions has not yet to be set.
                if(count <= 0){// if counter has yet to be set.
                    // SET DIRECTIONS FOR X AND Y;
                    for(int i = 0; i < spawn.length; i++){
                        EnemVel[i].y = 0;
                        Gdx.app.log(log, "Setting new EnemVel["+i+"] x and y");
                        setXDirection(chooseRandomDirection(),i);
                        setYDirection(chooseRandomDirection(),i);
                        Gdx.app.log(log, "New EnemVel["+i+"] x and y set");
                    }
                    // SET LOCK TO TRUE
                    lock = true;
                    // SET MOVING TO TRUE
                    moving = true;
                    // SET TIME LENGTH OF ENEMY MOVEMENT
                    count = 250;
                }
            }
        }
        else if(moving){// if enemy is on the move.
            if(count <= 0){// if time counter for enemy movement has finished.
                if(lock){// if directions are in used.
                    // SET MOVING TO FALSE. ENEMY IS NOW RESTING
                    moving = false;
                    // SET NEW TIME COUNTER FOR ENEMY WHILE AT REST
                    count = 500;
                    // SET LOCKS TO FALSE. DIRECTIONS ARE NOT IN USE.
                    lock = false;
                    // RANDOMIZE ENEMY MOVEMENT 
                    decision = false;
                }
            }
            else{// ENEMY IS STILL MOVING, ENEMY IS NOW MOVING.
                if(lock){// IF DIRECTIONS ARE STILL LOCKED.
                    for(int i=0; i<spawn.length; i++){
                        move(i);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }       

    else if(chasing){
        for(int i = 0; i < spawn.length; i++){

            //can't access EnemPos[i].x;
            EnemPos[i].x = 0;
            EnemPos[i].y = 0;

            Gdx.app.log(log, "Setting new EnemPos[" + i + "] x and y");
            Gdx.app.log(log, "Old EnemPos[" + Integer.toString(i) +"].x = " + Float.toString(EnemPos[i].x));
            EnemPos[i].x = Math.abs(spawn[i].x - tc.position.x);
            Gdx.app.log(log, "New EnemPos[" + Integer.toString(i) +"].x = " + Float.toString(EnemPos[i].x));

            Gdx.app.log(log, "Old EnemPos[" + Integer.toString(i) +"].y = " + Float.toString(EnemPos[i].y));
            EnemPos[i].y = Math.abs(spawn[i].y - tc.position.y);
            Gdx.app.log(log, "New EnemPos[" + Integer.toString(i) +"].y = " + Float.toString(EnemPos[i].y));
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < spawn.length; i++){
            if(EnemPos[i].y > EnemPos[i].x){
                EnemVel[i].y = velocity/2;
                EnemVel[i].x = velocity/3;
            }

            if(EnemPos[i].x > EnemPos[i].y){
                EnemVel[i].x = velocity/2;
                EnemVel[i].y = velocity/3;
            }
            if(EnemPos[i].x == 0){
                EnemVel[i].x = velocity;
                EnemVel[i].y = 0;
            }
            if(EnemPos[i].y == 0){
                EnemVel[i].x = velocity;
                EnemVel[i].x = 0;
            }
            if(EnemPos[i].y == EnemPos[i].x){
                EnemVel[i].y = velocity/3;
                EnemVel[i].x = velocity/3;
            }

            if (spawn[i].x > tc.position.x)
                {EnemVel[i].x*=-1;}
            if (spawn[i].y > tc.position.y)
                {EnemVel[i].y*=-1;}
        }
        if(count <= 0){
            if (chasing){//if enemy is chasing
                if(!lock){//lock is to check if counter has been set.
                    count = 200;
                    lock = true;
                }
                else{
                    lock = false;
                    chasing = false;
                }
            }

            else if(!chasing){//if enemy stopped chasing
                if(!lock){//lock is to check if counter has been set.
                    count = 300;
                    lock = true;
                    decision = false;
                }
                else{
                    lock = false;
                    chasing = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

every time i try to access EnemPos[i].x or spawn[i].x from inside the LogicChase method i always get the "java.lang.NullPointerException" at AI.logicChase(AI.java:218) or AI.logicChase(AI.java:142)

the code on AI.java:218 is

```
// **JAVA.LANG.NULL DETECTED AT THIS LINE OF CODE**
EnemPos[i].x = Math.abs(spawn[i].x - tc.position.x);
```

the code on AI.java:142 is

```
public void setXDirection(int dir, int i){
    Gdx.app.log(log, "Old EnemPos[" + Integer.toString(i) +"].x = " + Float.toString(EnemPos[i].x));
    EnemVel[i].x = dir;// **JAVA.LANG.NULL DETECTED AT THIS LINE OF CODE**
    Gdx.app.log(log, "New EnemPos[" + Integer.toString(i) +"].x = " + Float.toString(EnemPos[i].x));
}
```

my question is simple. WHY THE HELL IS IT NULL WHEN I ALREADY DECLARED VALUES FROM MY VECTOR2 VARIABLES?!

also for those who want to check the AI.java and TestColl.java here are the links.
http://www.mediafire.com/view/t6sz5ifsokch1av/AI.java
http://www.mediafire.com/view/6ssvky2zpuksbuk/TestColl.java

just replace the TestColl implements with application listener.

Comment: i only access PlaceEnemy(); once!

Comment: You have commented `//EnemPos[i] = new Vector2(x, y);`, so your array `EnemPos` have no element.

Comment: if going for a 50/50 chance of chase or not, why didn't you use `new Random().nextBoolean()`?

Comment: Hint: When you get a null pointer exception on a complex line, break it down into simple assignments to temps, so you will be able to tell which pointer in null.

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding. i commented it out because i moved EnemPos[i] = new Vector2(x, y); inside the logicChase method but still the same null point error when i call the array outside the AI.java class.

Comment: @tonithy - thanks for that i'll try using the code you provided now.

Comment: @HotLicks - i tried to put a log before assigning a new value on EnemPos[i].x which will print out on the console the value of it before it changes but sadly the nullpointer points at the log.

Comment: Please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Check/log EnemPos and EnemPos[i] separately, on separate lines.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't put elements in the array `EnemPos`. Try removing comment in the line

```
EnemPos[i] = new Vector2(x, y);
```

Comment: i commented it out because i moved EnemPos[i] = new Vector2(x, y); inside the logicChase method but still the same null point error when i call the array outside the AI.java class.

Comment: Short- null pointer error pops out when i access the vector array even though i already gave it some values.

Comment: Self-contained. I dont know what to give you there. Correct- if it was correct i dont need to bother other people about my problem. Examples are the codes.

Comment: @JCR10 - A *complete* stripped-down version that compiles and executes and still demonstrates the problem.  Something that others here can copy into a file and compile.

Comment: @HotLicks - is it ok to upload files here? because if not i might have to paste every code from 2 of my classes which would make this thread longer than it already is.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is all commented. I.e.: I cannot see from where the method `setXDirection` is being invoked (all commented out), but I guess is that you invoke that method **BEFORE** you invoke `public void PlaceEnemy()`, where you initialize your vectors in the Array.
Please double check this.
(If you could post correct code that would be fantastic)

Comment: sorry about that i'll update it now i'm still in the middle of debugging it that's why there's a lot of code that are commented out.